# How to concat a string to xsl:value-of select="...?

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="/*/properties/property[@name='report']/@value" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

Is there any way to concat another string to

```
<xsl:value-of select="/*/properties/property[@name='report']/@value"  />
```

I need to pass some text to href attribute in addition to the report property value

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can use the rather sensibly named xpath function called **concat** here

```
<a>
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('myText:', /*/properties/property[@name='report']/@value)" />
   </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

Of course, it doesn't have to be text here, it can be another xpath expression to select an element or attribute. And you can have any number of arguments in the concat expression.

Do note, you can make use of Attribute Value Templates (represented by the curly braces) here to simplify your expression

```
<a href="{concat('myText:', /*/properties/property[@name='report']/@value)}"></a>
```

Comment: @TimC: Good, but the `concat()` function isn't necessary here.

Comment: I have the following tag: `<a title="" href="/page.cfm?id=425">Anders, John</a>` and I would like to create a hidden field in XSLT which only takes the ID #. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 32):

Three Answers :

Simple :

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="//your/xquery/path"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="'vmLogo.gif'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Using 'concat' :

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(//your/xquery/path,'vmLogo.gif')"/>                    
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Attribute shortcut as suggested by @TimC

```
<img src="{concat(//your/xquery/path,'vmLogo.gif')}" />
```

Comment: As noted by Dimitre, you don't need the concat here: `<img src="{//your/xpath}vmLogo.gif" />`

Answer (score 17):

**Use**:

```
<a href="wantedText{/*/properties/property[@name='report']/@value)}"></a>
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to concat a static text string to a selected value is to use  element.

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="/*/properties/property[@name='report']/@value" />
    <xsl:text>staticIconExample.png</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest method is

```
  <TD>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(//author/first-name,' ',//author/last-name)"/>
  </TD>
```

when the XML Structure is

```
<title>The Confidence Man</title>
<author>
  <first-name>Herman</first-name>
  <last-name>Melville</last-name>
</author>
<price>11.99</price>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most readable solution, but you can mix the result from a value-of with plain text:

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href"> 
    Text<xsl:value-of select="/*/properties/property[@name='report']/@value"/>Text
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

Comment: This has some problems: between XSLT instructions, white space only text nodes are ignored; but now that you have a not white space only text node (`'              Text'`), white space (even new line) will be output.