# Xpath Get Full URL by combining a base URL with a string obtained from Xml

Tags: xml, xpath

I am getting a url form a HTML Page with this Xpath:

```
//*[@id="page"]/div[1]/table/tr[9]/td[2]/a/@href
```

This code Output show link like this

```
href="test/306811.zip"
```

I want add site domain to outupt like this:

```
href="http://domain.com/test/306811.zip"
```

How can do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395488/how-to-concat-a-string-to-xslvalue-of-select) or [string-join](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join), e.g.

```
concat('http://domain.com/', //*[@id="page"]/div[1]/table/tr[9]/td[2]/a/@href)
```